# Slicing lists by character

Tags: python

I am trying to slice a Python list to turn it into a 2d list. There are certain elements I want to skip.

```
myList = [1,"skip",3,4,"hop",7,6,"9",5,59,3,6,"skip",80,"skip","hop",78,67,827,64,53]
```

The output I was trying to get for the list is:

```
[[1, 'skip',3,4,'hop',7],[6,"9",5,59],[3,6,"skip",80,"skip","hop",78],[67,827,64,53]]
```

Basically I want 4 elements (excluding the "skips" and "hops") in each inner list.

I've tried different things but I keep getting the wrong output.

```
myList = [1,"skip",3,4,"hop",7,6,"9",5,59,3,6,"skip",80,"skip","hop",78,67,827,64,53]

a = [[],[],[],[]]

for k in range(len(a)):
    while len(a[k]) - a[k].count("skip") - a[k].count("hop") <4:
            for j in range(len(myList)):
                a[k] += [myList[j]]
```

Comment: You may need to check if an element is "skip" or "hop".

Comment: @MSH `.count("skip")` and `.count("hop")` seem to be used for this purpose.

Comment: What if it doesn't divide up evenly? Do you want a smaller-than-four list at the end?

Comment: You're pre-populating `a` with four empty sublists, which will only work as long as `myList` is basically identical to the example shown.  Do you want a general solution that can work even when `myList` has different contents?

Comment: @CrazyChucky, yes if the last list were smaller than 4 it would still be okay.

Comment: @JohnGordon, yes

Answer (score 0):

use a helper method to yield lists that match your desired conditions

```
def yield_parts(l):
    part = []
    count = 0
    for item in l:
        part.append(item)
        if item not in {"skip","hop"}: 
           count += 1
           if count == 4:
              yield part
              count = 0
              part = []
    if part:
       yield part
```

since it is a generator you will have to call `list` on the result as follows

```
L = [1,"skip",3,4,"hop",7,6,"9",5,59,3,6,"skip",80,"skip","hop",78,67,827,64,53]
print(list(yield_parts(L)))
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Basically I want 4 elements (excluding the "skips" and "hops") in each inner list. ..."*

Use a variable to keep a count of each *sub-list*, and decrement *i* when the value is *"skip"* or *"hop"*.

Here is an example.

```py
a, b, n = [], [], 0
for i, e in enumerate(myList):
    b.append(e)
    if e in ['skip', 'hop']: i -= 1
    else: n += 1
    if n == 4:
        a.append(b)
        b = []
        n = 0
```

Output

```
[[1, 'skip', 3, 4, 'hop', 7], [6, '9', 5, 59], [3, 6, 'skip', 80, 'skip', 'hop', 78], [67, 827, 64, 53]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Not really pretty, but works (using `itertools.groupby`):

```
from itertools import groupby
myList = [1,"skip",3,4,"hop",7,6,"9",5,59,3,6,"skip",80,"skip","hop",78,67,827,64,53]
numList = [-1]
for s in myList:
    numList.append(numList[-1] if s in ('skip', 'hop') else numList[-1]+1)
print([[v[0] for v in g] for _, g in groupby(zip(myList, numList[1:]), key=lambda kg: kg[1] // 4)])
```

Output:

```
[1, 'skip', 3, 4, 'hop', 7], [6, '9', 5, 59], [3, 6, 'skip', 80, 'skip', 'hop', 78], [67, 827, 64, 53]]
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to do what you want:

```py
myList = [1,"skip",3,4,"hop",7,6,"9",5,59,3,6,"skip",80,"skip","hop",78,67,827,64,53]
EXCLUDE_THESE = {'skip','hop'}

new_list = []
while len(new_list)==0 or sum([len(_) for _ in new_list])<len(myList):
    tmp = []
    count = -1
    start_here = sum([len(_) for _ in new_list]) if len(new_list) != 0 else 0
    for i,item in enumerate(myList[start_here:]):
        if item not in EXCLUDE_THESE:
            count += 1
        if count < 4:
            tmp.append(item)
    new_list.append(tmp)

print(new_list)
```

prints

```
[[1, 'skip', 3, 4, 'hop', 7], [6, '9', 5, 59], [3, 6, 'skip', 80, 'skip', 'hop', 78], [67, 827, 64, 53]]
```